# How do I get this formula to work and put the return function into the print statement so that it just outputs a money value?

Tags: python, function

```
def compound_interest(P, r, n, Y):
    '''
    Computes the future value of investment after Y years

    P: initial investment principal
    r: the annual interest rate
    n: the number of times per year interest will be compounded
    Y: the number of years over which to invest

    P = float(input("Enter your starting principal ($): "))
    r = float(input("Enter the annual interest rate (value between 0 and 1): "))
    n = float(input("Enter the number of times per year to compound interest: "))
    Y = float(input("Enter the number of years over which to invest: "))

    returns: the future value of investment
    '''
    compound_interest = ((P)((1+(r/n))**(ny)))
    print("After 10 year (s), you will have", "$" + str(compound_interest))
    return compound_interest
```

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
import math

def compound_interest():

    P = float(input("Enter your starting principal ($): "))
    r = float(input("Enter the annual interest rate (value between 0 and 1): "))
    n = float(input("Enter the number of times per year to compound interest: "))
    Y = float(input("Enter the number of years over which to invest: "))
    cpd_interest = P * math.pow(r+1, n * Y)
    print("After {} year (s), you will have {} $".format(Y, cpd_interest))
    return cpd_interest

compound_interest()
```

I've removed the parameters you give in your function, because you don't need them if you ask for them as `input()` from the user.

I also improved your calculation: When you want to calculate the interest it should be the starting principal * (the interest percentage +1 to the power (number of years times number of times per year)). I used the math.pow() function for this, and you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) how it works exactly.

I renamed the variable name from compound_interest to cpd_interest, as it's a bad idea to have variable names the same name as your function.

I also rewrote your print statement, and used a replacement field to correctly format the invested years & interest. You *cannot* return inside a print statement, returning is always the last thing the function does (unless it returns nothing).